# The method ***** is undefined for the type *******

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, undefined

i'm new to this forum, first of all i would like to say thanks for reviewing my question.

I'm receiving this message: The method CreandoFunciones() is undefined for the type CreandoFunciones. I'm new @ Java, i try a few things, but nothing.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
package funciones;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Funciones1 {

private static Scanner scan;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    CreandoFunciones link = new CreandoFunciones();
    {

        int menu;
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Opción: ");
        menu = scan.nextInt();

        switch(menu)
        {
        case 1: 
            link.CreandoFunciones();
            break;
        case 2:
               System.out.println("C'est la vie!");
               break;
        case 3:
                System.out.println("Alors on danse!");
                break;
        default: System.out.println("Owned.");      
        }

}
  }
}


package funciones;

public class CreandoFunciones {

public CreandoFunciones()
{
        System.out.println("Testing");
}

}
```

Comment: What do you think the error message is trying to tell you?

Comment: there is no method called `CreandoFunciones` in `CreandoFunciones`. what you have is the constructor...and you don't call constructors like that. Just do CreandoFunciones link = new CreandoFunciones() and you should see "Testing"

Comment: BTW `CreandoFunciones` is technically wrong. what you want to *create* is `metodos` since "functions" in classes are called "methods".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreandoFunciones()` is a constructor of the class not a usual method. So you cannot call like `link.CreandoFunciones();`. to perform operation in link 1 create a separate method in the class.

Comment: damn, so fast o_o...Thanks for reply....sooo what about if i change "public CreandoFunciones()" to "public void CreandoFunciones1()" and then i call it like this "link.CreandoFunciones1();" ?